# Validating Zend Forms with a Zend_Form_Element_File on mobile Safari

Tags: php, ios, zend-framework, mobile-safari, zend-form

I have a form that uses a Zend_Form_Element_File which isn't a required field.

When my form is submitted on an iPad it doesn't validate but also doesn't generate any error messages.

I have narrowed the problem down to the Zend_Form_Element_File. I appreciate that Mobile Safari doesn't support the file element but its not a required field so should just be ignored.

```
$profilePicture = new Zend_Form_Element_File('profilePicture');
$profilePicture->setLabel('Profile Picture')
               ->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpeg,jpg,png,gif')
               ->addValidator('FilesSize', false, 512000)
               ->addValidator('Count', false, 1)
               ->setDestination(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../../data/uploads/dogs/temp');
$this->addElement($profilePicture);
```

Am I missing anything that can get my form validating on the iPad?

Answer (score 1):

A Zend Framework issue has been posted here : [ZF-11485](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11485).

> If I validate this form with an Iphone/Ipad, in PHP, the global var $_FILES will be an empty array, but the Zend_Validate_File_Upload validator, used by Zend_File_Transfert_Adapter_Http, will detect this as a oversized file upload failure.

Being curious (I do not own an iOS device):

1. is the File Input displayed on the iPad?
2. can you display (var_dump...) the error messages?

Comment: I tried the var_dump and it just displays an empty array with no errors on any of the elements. The input shows but it is greyed out.